# Check All to Trigger Click or Change With Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I've been testing and researching this code, concerning the "check all" checkbox.
While I understand that if a checkbox is checked programmatically, 
first the click handler is called, then the checkbox state is changed, I would need to use a change handler.

The code I've been using utilizes parameters in the click handler.

Are parameters available to the change handlers, as well?

Below is the code, with the parameters being passed through the click handler, currently.
I've tried changing the .click to .change, but without effect.
In testing, each individual checkbox will trigger the function to make the div appear, but the 'check_all' checkbox does not trigger it.

Also available as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buck1115/fU8E9/).

Thanks for any help in this.

the CSS:

```
.toBeCompared_k {
        display: block;
}
.toBeCompared_s {
        display: block;
}
.toBeCompared_a {
        display: block;
}

.toBeCompared_new_k {
        display:inline-block;
        background:red;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
        float: left;
}
.toBeCompared_new_s {
        display: inline - block;
        background: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
        float: left;
}
.toBeCompared_new_a {
        display: inline - block;
        background: yellow;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin:2px;
        float:left;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#check_all").change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function dynamic_boxes() {
    $(".ksa_check_k").click({
        param1: "k",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);
    $(".ksa_check_s").click({
        param1: "s",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);
    $(".ksa_check_a").click({
        param1: "a",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);

    function cool_function(event) {
        var ksa_section = event.data.param1
        var title = $(this).closest('.ksa_check_group').find('.ksa_check_' + ksa_section).attr("id")
        //e.g. above returns ksa_on_1k1_1
        var title_partial = title.substring(nth_occurrence(title, '_', 2) + 1, nth_occurrence(title, '_', 3))
        //e.g. above returns 1k1
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var html = '<div id="' + title_partial + '"class="toBeCompared_new_' + ksa_section + '">' + title_partial + '</div>';
            $('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).append(html);
            $('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).show();
        } else {
            $('div[id="' + title_partial + '"]').remove();
        }
    }
});

function nth_occurrence(string, char, nth) {
    var first_index = string.indexOf(char);
    var length_up_to_first_index = first_index + 1;
    if (nth == 1) {
        return first_index;
    } else {
        var string_after_first_occurrence = string.slice(length_up_to_first_index);
        var next_occurrence = nth_occurrence(string_after_first_occurrence, char, nth - 1);
        if (next_occurrence === -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return length_up_to_first_index + next_occurrence;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="check_all">
<div class="ksa_check_group">
    <span>1k1</span><input id="ksa_on_1k1_1" class="ksa_check_k" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ksa_on_1k1_1">
</div>
<div class="ksa_check_group">
<span>1s1</span><input id="ksa_on_1s1_1" class="ksa_check_s" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ksa_on_1k1_1">
</div>
<div class="ksa_check_group">
<span>1a1</span><input id="ksa_on_1a1_1" class="ksa_check_a" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ksa_on_1k1_1">
</div>

<div class="toBeCompared_k"></div>
<div class="toBeCompared_s"></div>
<div class="toBeCompared_a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire the trigger on your checkboxes

```
  $('*[class^="toBeCompared_new_"]').hide();
  $('*[class^="ksa_check_"]').trigger("change");
```

[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/fU8E9/3/)

Comment: Thank you.  What function do the asterisk and caret play in the selectors?  Are they wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

(updated)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $(document).on("change", "#check_all", {
            boxes: $(".ksa_check_group > input[type=checkbox]")
        }, function (e) {
            $(e.target).attr("checked");        
            function toggle(_, o) {
                var _toggle = (o === false ? true : false);
                return _toggle
            };
            $(e.data.boxes).not(":checked").prop("checked", toggle).change();    
            if ($(e.target).hasClass("changed")) {
                $(e.data.boxes).prop("checked", !toggle).change()
                .each(function (i, el) {
                    $(el).on("click", function (e) {    
                        if ($(el).prop("checked") === false 
                           && $("#check_all").is(":checked")) {                              
                             $("#check_all")
                             .removeAttr("checked")
                             .toggleClass("changed")
                        };
                    })
                });
            };
            return $(e.target).toggleClass("changed");
        });


    function nth_occurrence(string, char, nth) {
        var first_index = string.indexOf(char);
        var length_up_to_first_index = first_index + 1;
        if (nth == 1) {
            return first_index;
        } else {
            var string_after_first_occurrence = string.slice(length_up_to_first_index);
            var next_occurrence = nth_occurrence(string_after_first_occurrence, char, nth - 1);
            if (next_occurrence === -1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return length_up_to_first_index + next_occurrence;
            }
        }
    };


    function cool_function(event) {
        var ksa_section = event.data.param1
        var title = $(this).closest('.ksa_check_group').find('.ksa_check_' + ksa_section).attr("id")
        //e.g. above returns ksa_on_1k1_1
        var title_partial = title.substring(nth_occurrence(title, '_', 2) + 1, nth_occurrence(title, '_', 3))
        //e.g. above returns 1k1
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            var html = '<div id="' + title_partial + '"class="toBeCompared_new_' + ksa_section + '">' + title_partial + '</div>';
            $('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).append(html);
            $('div.toBeCompared_' + ksa_section).show();
        } else {
            $('div[id="' + title_partial + '"]').remove();
        }
    };

    $(".ksa_check_k").change({
        param1: "k",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);
    $(".ksa_check_s").change({
        param1: "s",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);
    $(".ksa_check_a").change({
        param1: "a",
        param2: "World"
    }, cool_function);
});
```

jsfiddle, updated http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/65p5N/

Note Original post appear to include both `$(function(){})` and`$(document).ready(function(){})` ? see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks the help, with regard to this (and the reference).

Comment: Would there be a way to prevent the 'reverse' or 'unselect' from occurring when an individual box is checked, then the 'select all' box is checked?  For example, in your fiddle, when an individual box is checked, then the 'select all' box is checked, all boxes are unchecked, rather than checked.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't clear in my above post, in that I meant to say this: "is there a way, once you click on the 'select all' box, to check the individual boxes, and then have the 'select all' check box change state accordinly?"  For example, if I click on 'select all' then de-select each checkbox individually, until there are no selected individual checkboxes, can the 'select all' checkbox then be unchecked, so that it will be ready to be checked again?

Comment: @buck1112 Updated post and jsfiddle should accomplish the requirement. Try updated jsfiddle ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately, once the 'select all' checkbox is checked, if it is unchecked, the checkboxes (and divs) remain unaffected.  I am needing it to function in a 'show/hide' manner.

Comment: @buck1112 The requirement may be possible. Perhaps consider the logic if a 1, or 2, individual checkboxes are checked, then `check_all` is checked - What would be the required toggle effect outcome a) all boxes checked (selected), or b) all boxes unchecked (unselected) ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  If, for example, as your scenario stated, 2 individual checkboxes were checked, then check_all is checked, the required toggle effect outcome would be first: all boxes checked (selected), then second: all boxes unchecked (unselected).

Comment: Thanks!  I've been trying to get the "Select All" box to uncheck, if any of the separate checkboxes are unchecked.  Can the existing code be modified to do that?  This example shows the behavior desired.  http://jsfiddle.net/5XMW4/

Comment: @buck1112 See, try updated post. Note, Not precisely behaviour desired. Included uncheck `check_all` on individual `.ksa_check_group` within existing piece. Requires _2_ `click/change` on `check_all` before behaviour desired takes effect. Thanks